# Short story: Transported to the moon as criminal punishment, people doing crimes to go on purpose

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Not sure exactly when this was published. I think it was in Asimov's or Analog, but not sure on that. It might have been on one of the big-round-number anniversaries of Heinlein's, because it has a Heinlein tie-in.

The basic idea was, a variety of crimes had their punishments set to transportation to the lunar penal colony. The penal colony is similar to the one described in *The Moon is a Harsh Mistress*. As a result, many people did the calculation. Then they worked out the least serious crime that resulted in transportation. Then they went out to commit this crime, deliberately get caught, plead guilty, and get transported to the moon. Where they did their time, and then joined the colony. Thus, for the cost of being in the jail on the moon for some time, they got a trip to the moon.

The main drama of the story was a couple who pulled a stick-up of a corner drug store. They were distraught because the heist went horribly wrong, resulting in a bystander getting shot. After all, these were not hardened professional criminals, just first-timers not trying to get the money but trying to get caught.

Comment: I remember reading this one. It feels like something from Asimov's in the 1980s. I add more if I can recall the details.

Comment: I think this dates from earlier than @DoscoJones's recollection, but I can't recall enough to get a proper start hunting.

Comment: I have read a similar story, but as I misremember it the criminals were mostly elderly, and the repentant one was an arsonist.  Possibly by Asimov.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a great match, since the publication history doesn't really fit, but many of these elements fit the short story "[Breathes There a Man](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?89552)" (1953) by Charles E. Fitch.  Originally published in *Rocket Stories*, July 1953 it apparently only subsequently appeared in the author collection [*Horses' Asteroid*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?17341).

Nevertheless, the story features a liveable but very socially constrained life on Earth that many people chaffed at, and an ever-present threat of exile to the Lunar Prison Colony for people found guilty of crimes.  The protagonist, and the woman he is in love with, belong to an underground of people dedicated to overthrowing the powers that rule Earth, but they are apparently betrayed, caught and "exiled" to the (vastly better/more free) conditions of the Moon.